# How do I update attribute values in a composer attribute table?

Tags: attribute-table, print-composer, fields-attributes

QGIS 2.18.13/Linux Mint 18.1, XFCE (but really Mate) 64 bit.

I have a configured an attribute table in a print composer, it pulls values from an imported (GE) KML layer, "name" and "description" (and lat/lon).  These display nicely.  But I updated the values in GE and these updates are not reflected in the attribute table.  I've pressed the "refresh table data" button and the "refresh view" button (many times) and even restarted to no avail.

Looking at the top values in for the field values in the Print Composer->Attributes->Expression Dialog window,  I get this (old, not refreshed) list:
[image: not synchronized list of field values]

While looking at the same data via the label tool in map mode Map->Layer->Properties->Label With->Expression Dialog (not composer mode), I see the correct, current values:
[image: correct current values]

I'd think the table data should update both in map mode and in composer mode, but barring that, is there a way to update the attribute table in composer?  Do I need to delete all tables and recreate them every time the underlying field values change to get them to update?